# Combine .csv files on Mac OSX terminal does not use a new line in between

Tags: macos, csv, terminal

I have multiple csv files that I wish to merge into one.

`a.csv`

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

`b.csv`

```
Field4,Field5,Field6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

When I run the following command on Mac OSX Terminal

```
cat *.csv >merged.csv
```

The files get concatenated as follows -

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
1,2,3
4,5,6Field4,Field5,Field6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

However I would like the concatenation to take place in a seperate line.

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
1,2,3
4,5,6
Field4,Field5,Field6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

How can this be done best?

```
cat *.csv + new line >merged.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your first file (and probably the rest as well) doesn't have a newline at the end of the last line. In unix-style text files, every line is supposed to have a newline terminator at the end. Result: when you catenate the files together, there's no terminator at the end of the "4,5,6" line, so "Field4,Field5,Field6" gets treated as part of the same line.

Fortunately, there's a pretty simple solution: use something that processes (and appends) files line-by-line rather than just blindly sticking them together. Here's an example using `awk`:

```
awk '{print $0}' *.csv
```

BTW, I wouldn't recommend using the format `somecmd *.csv >merged.csv`, because merged.csv can wind up being both an input and output, leading to weird results. Whether this happens (and whether it matters) is complicated, but it's best to just avoid the issue by using a more specific wildcard pattern, putting the input and output in different directories, or something like that.